# Conditional Formatting - data sheet cell needs to change colour if 1 is present on previous spreadsheet

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have 2 spreadsheets. One with data and the other represented with 1's. My aim is to flag in green on the data sheets where 1's are present on the other spreadsheet.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First select just 1 cell from the data spreadsheet. Then go to conditional formatting in the Home tab and click on New Rule. There again select the last option 'Use a formula to determine which cells to format'. Then you will get a blank box. Inside that write your formula, add the relevant fill color and then you will be able to color all your relevant cells in the data spreadsheet. In the formula you can write something like: =Sheet2!D4=1 if you want to color the Sheet1 D4 cell if value of Sheet2 D4 is 1. Then you can just copy the cell that has the conditional formatting and paste it as format to other cells so that the conditional formatting is applied to other cells as well.

Comment: You don't realise how happy you've made me!!! So easy to understand also. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Happy to help you :)